# How to fix unable to create API App in West US 2

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps

I have been facing an issue where I get an error when trying to deploy an API App to West US 2. It works in, say, West US, tho.

Here is the error:
[image]

I am deploying a Standard 1 Windows .NET 6 API App with no fancy networking or anything like that.

Comment: How you are deploying the Application?

Comment: The error clearly states that you have exceeded the `quota`. only 1 instance per subscription is allowed for you - may be you are on free tier. create in different subscription if you have one or region.

Comment: @Harshitha I am deploying via Azure Portal (portal.azure.com)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran no one is aware of any limitations in place, we are not on a free sub, and we don't even have 1 instance in use.

Comment: @MattM - Try to change the SKU plan and check once.

Comment: @Harshitha changing SKU does not work

Comment: What about different region?

Comment: Yes, as stated, I can create in different regions, just not West US 2

Comment: The limit issue is only for particular resource group, not for the entire subscription.Try to deploy to another resource group with same region and check once.

Comment: Refer this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-sku-not-available?tabs=azure-portal) once.

Comment: I tried creating in all new (new resource group, etc) and it failed with the same error.

Answer (score -1):

The error indicates that there is no limit to deploy your App in the selected region and the selected resource group.

The mentioned limit is for the selected `resource group`/`App Service Plan` not for the `subscription`.

If you want to deploy only in that specific region, try to select another `App Service Plan`,deploy the app and check once.

Also, check the `vCPU` limit of your selected Plan.

[image]

- Try to delete or decrease the number of instances in that particular `App Service Plan` in which you are facing the issue.

[image]

Please refer similar issue in [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/736717/linux-app-service-with-php-error-this-region-has-q) for more details.

Comment: The error does not indicate resource group limitations. It says specifically the region has a quota for my subscription.

Comment: Have you tried in another app service plan with same region.

Comment: I've tried different SKUs, yes